# Highcharts export in IE malformed

Tags: internet-explorer, highcharts, export

Our app that uses Highcharts 2.2.1 fails to render any export options (JPG, PNG and PDF) properly in IE10.

Generally applies to all chart types which are malformed in result.

In spline type, a weird transform of data points is being done with this result, they are transformed to a grey strong line. Seems like the original spline border is thicker and in front of points (just a guess). In Piechart mode, original colors are transformed to grey. This also happens in Column charts.

As I am not able to insert here more than 2 links, so I include weird behaviour images for spline chart type, which is probably worst:

[original chart screenshot](http://gajdos.kurzor.net/charts/normal.png)
[exported chart - image taken from export directly](http://gajdos.kurzor.net/charts/normal.jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts 3.0, we rebuild some elements in Core, so I advice to update to Highcharts 3.0.2 and to the newest jquery, then all problems should disappear.